# Does GET endpoint triggers underlying APIs on request (with Postman or JMeter)

Tags: api, jmeter, postman

I'm creating `load testing` with JMeter.
We have A Single Page Application (React).
Let's say I need to check the endpoint

`GET /foo`

When you go to that endpoint via the browser it triggers API endpoints (javascript fetch) to retrieve data. Let's say 2 endpoints

`GET /api/fooData`, `GET /api/fooCalendar`

My question is: If I request `GET /foo` with JMeter (or Postman for instance), will it trigger the other endpoints behind the scene like a normal user flow, or I would need to manually check all the endpoints that are being triggered?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I had the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.** Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So you will have to create separate [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers for each JavaScript-driven calls. If the calls are made in parallel - it would be better to put them under the [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter) as JMeter executes Samplers sequentially (upside down)